# How can I list all pages of a site that use a certain font?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts, console.log

We use a lot of fonts on our website and we want to unify them. Can I use the console to see what font each page of the site is using? In terms of even managing licenses for certain fonts. So we don't want the font TheSansCE, etc. to be present on the whole page. We know that this font appears on some pages and we need to find out which.

So I need to list all urls that use a specific font.

Ideally one of these two solutions:

**a) Select all pages with a certain font.**
results:[example.com/dot-dot - font: Arial, Calibri, example.com/bot-bot - font: Arial, example.com/derp - font: Calibri]

**b) After entering the font name, list url addresses .**
The font I entered: Arial, results: example.com/dot-dot, example.com/bot-bot

The listing should include all pages with fonts that are actually used on the specific page (I don't want to list all fonts that are in css styles)

I found only these solutions:

**1. First - all urls of the website**

```js
var urls = [];

for (var i = document.links.length; i-- > 0;)
  if (document.links[i].hostname === location.hostname)
    urls.push(document.links[i].href);

console.log(urls);
```

**2. Second - all fonts on the website**

```js
function styleInPage(css, verbose) {
  if (typeof getComputedStyle == "undefined")
    getComputedStyle = function(elem) {
      return elem.currentStyle;
    }

  var who, hoo, val, 
    values = [],
    nodes = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    L = nodes.length;
    
  for (var i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    who = nodes[i];
    
    if (who.style) {
      hoo = '#' + (who.id || who.nodeName + '(' + i + ')');
      val = who.style.fontFamily || getComputedStyle(who, '')[css];
      
      if (val) {
        if (verbose) values.push([hoo, val]);
        else if (values.indexOf(val) == -1) values.push(val);
      }

      val_before = getComputedStyle(who, ':before')[css];
      
      if (val_before) {
        if (verbose) values.push([hoo, val_before]);
        else if (values.indexOf(val_before) == -1) values.push(val_before);
      }
      
      val_after = getComputedStyle(who, ':after')[css];
      
      if (val_after) {
        if (verbose) values.push([hoo, val_after]);
        else if (values.indexOf(val_after) == -1) values.push(val_after);
      }
    }
  }
  return values;
}

alert(styleInPage('fontFamily')); // returns array:
```

I get here all urls without any condition or all fonts without any specific URL.

Comment: any suggestion please? :(